# Topology and countable base

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, general-topology

I wish to show that if the topological space X has a countable base, then every base contains a countable base. I know if if a space has a countable base, then it has countable dense subset but they are not the same statements apparently~

Comment: No, it's not the same.

Comment: Yaa so I am wondering how to approach the problem of proving every base contains a countable base~

Comment: @Homaniac: Under what conditions? That a countable base exists?

Comment: Hint: if $\mathcal B$ is countable, then $\mathcal B\times\mathcal B$ is countable.

Comment: and the latter is a subset of the former?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not true that a topological space $X$ has a countable base if and only if it has a countable dense set (only the forward implication holds).  Consider $\mathbb R$ with the topology generated by the basis $\{[x,x+\varepsilon):x\in\mathbb R, \varepsilon>0\}$ (sometimes called the lower limit topology).  Then, as with the standard topology, $\mathbb Q$ is a countable dense set.

However, there is no countable base.  For if $\mathcal B$ is a base, then for each $x\in\mathbb R$ there is some $B_x\in\mathcal B$ such that $x\in B_x\subset[x,x+1)$.  If $x\neq y$, then $B_x\neq B_y$, and therefore $\mathcal B$ is uncountable.

---

Here is how you can get started with your question.  Suppose $\mathcal B=\{B_n\}$ is a countable base for $X$, and let $\mathcal C$ be a base for the topology on $X$.  Whenever it is possible, choose some $C_{n,m}\in\mathcal C$ such that $B_m\subset C_{n,m}\subset B_n$.

Comment: I only wish to show that the topological space X has a countable base implies every base contains a countable base.